# sort rows by multiple scenarios

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to sort rows based on multiple Values. In this example I am trying to separate the matching "Product SN"(Column M) and "CE Name" (Column L) that have a "220 - Replaced Component" action Code (Column N) into one sheet and the ones without "220" into another sheet.

E.g.

- C-666 LC011169 does not have a "220" present and should be on one sheet
- C-958 LC011169 has a "220" and should be on its own sheet

[image: Example Excel]

I know this might seem confusing but I will have to sort hundreds of line items like this every day and I'm working on streamlining the process.

A simplified version would look like the below image (where **X=Replaced**):

[image]

To go even further I'm trying to combine the "symptoms codes" (Column O) once the first operation is complete. This is my ultimate goal where the **Symbols are the Symptoms**:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a fixed list of names and serials? If yes,  you could do a pivot table for each of them. Our what about having only one pivot table and filtering it?

Comment: What is the output supposed to look like?  Are you only interested in columns L and M, so you want to create two new tables with just cols L, M, and N?  It isn't clear what "matching" means.  What will change in other scenarios?

Comment: This will be new data every day. my ultimate goal is to sort the line items be weather the "product serial" has been replaced. (Column L) is an experience number. so one serial can have multiple experience number but can only be replaced for one experience

Comment: I edited the question hopefully I cleared it up a little better let me know

Answer (score 0):

I experimented with some VBA to sort and copy.

See linked xlsm file at the end for further info.

So what we have here is a VBA code that sorts the original information (just copying, not touching the original list) into three new tables.

What it does:

- Goes through the entire original table
- Copies each row to a new, pre-defined and and existing table on a different sheet.

What it doesn't do:

- Check for duplicates
- Creates new tables

It also includes a macro to clear the sorted tables. This could also be used to clear the tables before sorting a second time, to avoid getting duplicates.

Sorting Code (this can most likely be improved, but it's getting late):

```
Sub sortToTables()
    Dim i, iLastRow As Integer
    Dim oLastRow As ListRow
    Dim srcRow As Range
    Dim Replaced As String, Burn As String, Repurpose As String
    iLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count

    Replaced = "220 - Replaced Component"
    Burn = "C990 - Advised to burn"
    Repurpose = "130 - Repurpose"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
        If Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(i, 13) = Replaced Then
        Set srcRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(i).Range
        Set oLastRow = Worksheets("220").ListObjects("Table16").ListRows.Add
        srcRow.Copy
        oLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(i, 13) = Burn Then
        Set srcRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(i).Range
        Set oLastRow = Worksheets("C990").ListObjects("Table17").ListRows.Add
        srcRow.Copy
        oLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        ElseIf Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(i, 13) = Repurpose Then
        Set srcRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(i).Range
        Set oLastRow = Worksheets("130").ListObjects("Table18").ListRows.Add
        srcRow.Copy
        oLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Code for clearing the tables:

```
Sub ResetTable()

Dim tbl As ListObject, tbl2 As ListObject, tbl3 As ListObject

Set tbl = Worksheets("220").ListObjects("Table16")
Set tbl2 = Worksheets("C990").ListObjects("Table17")
Set tbl3 = Worksheets("130").ListObjects("Table18")


  If tbl.ListRows.Count >= 1 Then
    tbl.DataBodyRange.Delete
  End If

  If tbl2.ListRows.Count >= 1 Then
    tbl2.DataBodyRange.Delete
  End If

  If tbl3.ListRows.Count >= 1 Then
    tbl3.DataBodyRange.Delete
  End If

End Sub
```

File:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_8icTMsheWfTUV0YjJCaElmTkU

**EDIT**

Update on the code to do what you commented (I think):

```
Sub sortToTables()
    Dim i, iLastRow As Integer
    Dim oLastRow As ListRow
    Dim srcRow As Range
    Dim Replaced As String, Burn As String, Repurpose As String
    iLastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows.Count

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To iLastRow

        If Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(i, 11) = "C-235" And _
            Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(i, 12) = "LC0001234" And _
            (InStr(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(i, 13), "220") Or _
            InStr(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").DataBodyRange(i, 13), "221")) Then

            Set srcRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(i).Range
            Set oLastRow = Worksheets("220").ListObjects("Table16").ListRows.Add
            srcRow.Copy
            oLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Else
            Set srcRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1").ListRows(i).Range
            Set oLastRow = Worksheets("C990").ListObjects("Table17").ListRows.Add
            srcRow.Copy
            oLastRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

As you can see here, I use `Instr` to get a partial match on a string, instead of an absolute value, since the cell contain more than just the number.

If you want to check against say, different serials, then you can assign that value to a variable instead, and enter the number serial you wish to sort in a textbox.

*I didn't bother to rename the sheets, but I only use two of the sheets in this example.*

Clarification on how to write the If statement – note the parenthesis around OR:

```
If ref(x,y) = "string" And ref(x,y2) = "another string" And (ref(x,y3) ="this" Or (ref(x,y3) ="that") Then

   Do stuff

Else '(Or ElseIf)

   Do something else

End If
```

Comment: this is awesome work and I really appreciate it. it doesn't quite do what im looking for. this one separates all of one cause code type to one sheet and another cause code type to another sheet. what I need is a little more complex then that unfortunately. I guess if I was to write it out lets see... **if** "row 1,2,3 column L = c235 and row 1,2,3 Column M = LC0001234 and row 1,2,3 Column N Contains a value of 220 or 221" **then** "Move row 1,2,3 to Sheet 2".

Comment: **if** "row 1,2,3 column L = c235 and row 1,2,3 Column M = LC0001234 and row 1,2,3 Column N does not Contain a value of 220 or 221" **then** "Move row 1,2,3 to Sheet 3"

Comment: I know this is all done on your free time and I really appreciate the effort I hope its not to much of a hassle and anything is much appreciated thank you again

Comment: Ah, well this is just sorting one column. You can just replace the If statements as you like to suit your needs. I'll update with an example of what you said.

Comment: @Mark Did you manage to work it out?